# Security issues regarding links in PHPBB2

Tags: php, security, phpbb

I've recently edited some regexps on a phpbb2's bbcode.php and I'm wondering if it'd bring security issues (regarding script injection from href, mainly (if it's even possible)).

I edited only the [url], [url=] and my newly created [url=""] bbcode tags.

Their original regexps (dated to 2008) didn't allow "invalid" characters such as parentheses or white spaces in the url value (which are needed for some Wikipedia pages and file hosting services' URLs), so instead of encoding the URLs' special characters as suggested by others, I just edited the regex to allow alphanumeric characters in the protocols and basically any character in the domain/rest of the url address.

The new regexps inside phpbb2's bbencode_second_pass function ($text = post's text):

```
// matches a [url]xxxx://www.phpbb.com[/url] code..
$patterns[] = "#\[url\]([\w]+?://.*?)\[/url\]#is";
$replacements[] = $bbcode_tpl['url1'];

// [url]www.phpbb.com[/url] code.. (no xxxx:// prefix).
$patterns[] = "#\[url\]((www|ftp)\..*?)\[/url\]#is";
$replacements[] = $bbcode_tpl['url2'];

// [url=xxxx://www.phpbb.com]phpBB[/url] code..
$patterns[] = "#\[url=([\w]+?://.*?)\]([^?\n\r\t].*?)\[/url\]#is";
$replacements[] = $bbcode_tpl['url3'];

// [url=www.phpbb.com]phpBB[/url] code.. (no xxxx:// prefix).
$patterns[] = "#\[url=((www|ftp)\..*?)\]([^?\n\r\t].*?)\[/url\]#is";
$replacements[] = $bbcode_tpl['url4'];


// [url="xxxx://www.phpbb.com"]phpBB[/url] code..
$patterns[] = "#\[url=&quot;([\w]+?://.*?)&quot;\]([^?\n\r\t].*?)\[/url\]#is"; //closes on first "]
//$patterns[] = "#\[url=&quot;([\w]+?://.*?)&quot;\](?![\w\n\s]*&quot;\])([^?\n\r\t].*?)\[/url\]#is"; //closes on last "] //discarded, ambigous
$replacements[] = $bbcode_tpl['url3'];

// [url="www.phpbb.com"]phpBB[/url] code.. (no xxxx:// prefix).
$patterns[] = "#\[url=&quot;((www|ftp)\..*?)&quot;\]([^?\n\r\t].*?)\[/url\]#is";
$replacements[] = $bbcode_tpl['url4'];


// [email]user@domain.tld[/email] code..
$patterns[] = "#\[email\]([a-z0-9&\-_.]+?@[\w\-]+\.([\w\-\.]+\.)?[\w]+)\[/email\]#si";
$replacements[] = $bbcode_tpl['email'];


$text = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $text);

// Remove our padding from the string..
$text = substr($text, 1);

return $text;
```

And the unedited phpbb2 declarations:

```
$bbcode_tpl['url1'] = str_replace('{URL}', '\\1', $bbcode_tpl['url']);
$bbcode_tpl['url1'] = str_replace('{DESCRIPTION}', '\\1', $bbcode_tpl['url1']);

$bbcode_tpl['url2'] = str_replace('{URL}', 'http://\\1', $bbcode_tpl['url']);
$bbcode_tpl['url2'] = str_replace('{DESCRIPTION}', '\\1', $bbcode_tpl['url2']);

$bbcode_tpl['url3'] = str_replace('{URL}', '\\1', $bbcode_tpl['url']);
$bbcode_tpl['url3'] = str_replace('{DESCRIPTION}', '\\2', $bbcode_tpl['url3']);

$bbcode_tpl['url4'] = str_replace('{URL}', 'http://\\1', $bbcode_tpl['url']);
$bbcode_tpl['url4'] = str_replace('{DESCRIPTION}', '\\3', $bbcode_tpl['url4']);
```

This works perfectly fine with my debugging so far, now I'd like to ask if, by allowing any character to be placed inside the A tag's href attribute I'd exposing my users or myself to any hacker attack?

Say, I tested the javascript URI hack (javascript:) and it doesn't seem to work even on Internet Explorer, and I don't know of any way of injecting a script through the href attribute of an A tag, would there be any risk in allowing my users to type whatever they like (as long as there's either a valid alphanumeric protocol such as *:// or www. which will have a http:// placed prior to it) in the href of  tags?

Please note that I'm not considering linking to malicious sites, I want to know if hackers would be able to inject scripts/cookies/whatever through the href of an  tag without the user clicking on it!

Now it sounds a little redundant to have a href attribute run anything without its  tag being clicked, but anyway, is there a way for a hacker to inject malicious code/javascript in the document through the href attribute?

Comment: Whitespace and carriage returns are illegal in URLs and against the spec. Space characters should be encoded as `%20`. If you must include carriage returns / line endings, you can do so with `%0A` and/or `%0D` as needed

Comment: If you're referring to RFC specs, even parentheses would be illegal then, and they're needed for some Wikipedia pages. I know that encoding could be a nice solution, but I'm not going to ask my end users to know how to encode their own URLs, and in phpbb it wouldn't be much differently than what is implemented: phpbb allows the user to type white space with my mod, but when the HTML is generated, all illegal characters are correctly encoded - say, `[url=www.a.com/a a]...[/url]` turns into `<a href="http://www.a.com/a%20a">...</a>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven’t tested it myself, but the following might still work:

```
[url]javascript://%0Aalert(1)[/url]
[url=javascript://%0Aalert(1)]…[/url]
[url="javascript://%0Aalert(1)"]…[/url]
```

These should all result in the following JavaScript code as `%0A` is decoded to a newline character:

```
//
alert(1)
```

---

Next guess: As you’re allowing any character, including the attribute value delimiting `"`, these might work:

```
[url]http://example.com/" onclick="alert(1)[/url]
[url=http://example.com/" onclick="alert(1)]…[/url]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've tested it before and, even though it has a "://" string which should define a protocol, the phpbb2 doesn't accept it as a valid address.

I've tested your given URL with these variations:


`[url="http://%0Aalert(1)"]…[/url]`
`[url="java://%0Aalert(1)"]…[/url]`
`[url="aaaaaaaaaa://%0Aalert(1)"]…[/url]` which are all valid URLs to the phpbb, however, any variation of "javascript://" is simply blocked and shown as pure text for some reason (a security check which I don't know of?)

Comment: @FabrícioMatté This is probably due to the replacement of `script:` by `script&#58;` at the begin of `bbencode_second_pass` that prevents the pattern `[\w]+?:` from matching.

Comment: about `[url=http://example.com/" onclick="alert(1)]…[/url]` it's transformed into `<a href="http://example.com/%22%20onclick=%22alert%281%29">…</a>`, as all special (invalid) URL characters are transformed in html by the phpbb when creating the links. That includes the HTML characters `<>"&` as well as any non-standard UTF-8 characters. Thanks for your help again. :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking through phpbb3.1's regex patterns, it does also accept any character in the URLs (the links are transformed to html as in the examples below) and it doesn't accept a javascript:// protocol so it's rather safe for now. I'll focus more in the phpbb3 security issues now for when the board software is upgraded.

Comment: There are no security issues in phpBB 3, but there are in phpBB 2. If you want to remain secure, upgrade!